# Modify the prompt in the root mode (zsh)

Tags: zsh, prompt, macos-catalina, zshrc

I changed the prompt in the user mode by following these steps :

1. create a **.zshrc** file
2. define a prompt (`$PROMPT=" %m%# >> "`)
3. `source .zshrc`

When I switch to root mode, it shows a different prompt. What do I have to do to set the same prompt with only the privilege symbol (% #) changing ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

When you define your `PROMPT` in your users `.zshrc` it's loaded when that user starts a new shell. When changing to root, you're logging in with different user and zsh checks `/root/.zshrc` instead of your users folder.

So you can either modify the roots zshrc or do the changes globally.
The global configuration resides in `/etc/zsh/` folder. There you can create a file named `zshrc` which is executed by all users on the system when starting zsh shell. For other configuration files you can check [Zsh on Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#Startup/Shutdown_files)

Comment: Thank you. It is exactly what I needed. 
I was also looking for the default prompt and I found the $PS1 in the exact ```/etc/zshrc/``` file. It even answers to that.